# Do we know which GIT command access remote, which does not?

Tags: git

As far as I know, not every GIT commands need to access remote. For example, if I just need to commit to local master branch, I can just do "git commit". In this case, it's only when I do push, i.e., "git push origin master", at which time, I know for sure git program needs to go to remote.
Other commands, such as "git status", seem to access remote as well because it can give hint when your local repo is not updated from remote.

So is there a comprehensive list of all the commands which reach out to remote repository? It helps me to know which GIT command I can still use when I'm offline.

Comment: `Other commands, such as "git status", seem to access remote as well` It doesn't

Comment: Status doesn't contact the remote at that moment. It reports based on the information that it has on the remote from last interaction with it.

Comment: Oh.... and then you can use any other. It's one of the basics of it being a _distributed_ VCS. You can do anything locally except for fetch/pull/push (unless it!s also another in-the-box repo)... and a few _remote_ subcommands, as explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git only requires an Internet connection when you use commands such as `git remote`, `git pull`, `git fetch`, and `git push` with a remote repository that is stored on an Internet server.

More on [Pro Git](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2) Book.

Comment: Only some subcommands of `git remote` (I think just `prune` and `update`) communicate with a remote; all the others simply configure the local repository to communicate with a remote.

Comment: `git ls-remote`

Comment: Some `git submodule` subcommands also contact remote.

Comment: The answer is totally incomplete

Comment: @PhilippeF  Can you elaborate, or provide a complete list?

Comment: @MingD. I with I could but not really. It's just that this answer is not a thorough analysis of all the possible git commands and which one interact with a remote. It's a "quick and dirty" answer. It does deserve in my opinion to be marked as an official answer.